# Uber Type, Passenger and Driver App with one Meteor App Backend

Tags: meteor

How to achieve two different mobile app, for example "Uber Taxi" type of app; with one Passenger/Client Mobile App and another for Driver Mobile App. Both have very different function.

As expected, both are connected to the same Meteor backend. Tried to search Meteor related blogs post but can't really find a proper solution.

Is Meteor do not have such solution ready?

Comment: this is possible by having 2 meteor app pointing to same Mongo Database.
As in Uber Each App will be one Project

Comment: So create two different project using Meteor CLI and point to same DB.

Comment: That seems like a hack solution... So there is no native Meteor solution I guess.

Comment: If you need 2 apps you will need 2 projects ..